# Set language for google docs in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-docs, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have some tests that use selenium firefoxDriver. I want to open some google documents (document, spreadsheet) as an anonymous user. How to ensure that the display language is English ?

I tried :

```
profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en");
```

This works for changing the language of **google.com** page, but not the **docs.google.com**

Comment: Apparently if you are not logged in the docs are displayed on the language that matches with your IP.

Comment: doesn't look like it. I tried to open a document anonymously in the browser and I have it in English. I can see a NID cookie in the request that I send directly from the browser and it seems that it's used to store preferences. Is there any way to replicate this using selenium?